# I am not sure I understand how pool based allocators deallocate

Tags: c, memory, memory-management, computer-science, allocation

I am trying to understand how pool based memory allocators work, and I think I understand how allocation works (which is very fast and requires 0 storage overhead) but here is my question:

Let's say there is an allocator which just keeps a linked list of pools and when you allocate, goes to the last element, looks in the free list, if there is anything in there, gives you that, and if not, allocates a new pool.

When you deallocate the memory for example

```
void* p = pool_alloc(32);
pool_free(p, 32); // <--- here deallocation happens
```

How does the pool allocator knows which one of the pools does the pointer belong to, given only the address and O(1) complexity (not searching the whole linked lists of pools)?

Thanks

Comment: Usually it would allocate a few bytes extra in front of the returned pointer, where such information is stored.

Comment: Are there any other ways around? In C++17 stdlib theres an allocator called unsychronized_pool_resource which does allocate 16 byte blocks without space overhead (tested using by allocating 2 16 byte items and printing difference between them which was 16 byte (item size))

Comment: Based on its description that allocator has a single pool per allocation size (presumably rounded to next power of two), so it can determine which pool an object was allocated in based on the size parameter which is also passed to the deallocation function

Comment: @UnholySheep it says the pool has a collection of chunks, how does it know what chunk does a pointer belong to?

Comment: There is no need to know which chunk some memory belongs to when the memory is returned to the pool. Returning memory to the pool only adds to the free list

Comment: @UnholySheep OHHHHHHHHHH right. thanks a lot I truly appreciate your answers! :))))